# Microsoft Graph API Calendar API Null SeriesMasterId

Tags: rest, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

### Solution Below ! ! !

This my friends, is a beautiful msft graph api call that filters, the top 50 calendar results by a not null SeriesMasterId! Also keep in mind, if this top 50 filter is not defined, the json returned only shows the **FIRST 10 RESULTS** from your calendar that match your query.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2015-10-20T10:13:32-07:00&endDateTime=2016-10-20T10:13:32-07:00&$select=subject,type,seriesMasterId&$top=50&$filter=seriesMasterId ne null`

### Original Post Below

I am having issues with retrieving a **SeriesMasterId** for recurring calendar events using the Microsoft Graph API. I am using the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer) logged in with my @{alias}.microsoft.com account to test, as I am a currently a Microsoft employee. The SeriesMasterId is always returned as null for my recurring events :/ when I make my REST call.

Here's the call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
```

Thanks for your time and any feedback on why I am getting this null SeriesMasterId or what is returned in your use cases for this call is much appreciated!

Get ISO 8601 timestamps from [here](http://coderstoolbox.net/unixtimestamp/).

I also get the following result when using a call to filter a series like the following.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2016-09-30T15:57:28-07:00&endDateTime=2016-10-20T10:13:32-07:00
```

Result

```
{
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"KD/rRxyX+ESoOfWCZfnfFwAANhX0Bw==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADc5NzQyYWI2LWMxOTctNDRmZi05ZTA3LWE3NmRmYmY1MDQ0MgBGAAAAAADXlwbV2STsRLeDUWHghS8MBwDHXzszvWCLTrbQs5TTKyesAAAAtujXAAAoP_tHHJf4RKg59YJl_d8XAAAEs3bpAAA=",
            "createdDateTime": "2015-09-21T16:45:22.8816871Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-10-02T15:47:15.0711136Z",
            "changeKey": "KD/rRxyX+ESoOfWCZfnfFwAANhX0Bw==",
            "categories": [],
            "originalStartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "responseStatus": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000F07EA63A52F4D001000000000000000010000000FF2DCB149338304FB698D41CCC6A4BF7",
            "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
            "isReminderOn": false,
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "subject": "Azure 532",
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n<meta name=\"ProgId\" content=\"Word.Document\">\r\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 15\">\r\n<meta name=\"Originator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 15\">\r\n<link rel=\"File-List\" href=\"cid:filelist.xml@01D0F452.3AA54670\"><style>\r\n<!--\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\"}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri}\r\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0in;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif}\r\na:link, span.MsoHyperlink\r\n\t{color:#0563C1;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline}\r\na:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed\r\n\t{color:#954F72;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline}\r\nspan.EmailStyle17\r\n\t{font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:windowtext}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body lang=\"EN-US\" link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\" style=\"\">\r\n<div class=\"WordSection1\">\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">&nbsp;</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
            },
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "importance": "normal",
            "sensitivity": "normal",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2015-10-02T15:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2015-10-03T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "location": {
                "displayName": "",
                "address": {}
            },
            "isAllDay": false,
            "isCancelled": false,
            "isOrganizer": true,
            "recurrence": null,
            "responseRequested": true,
            "seriesMasterId": null,
            "showAs": "busy",
            "type": "singleInstance",
            "attendees": [
                {
                    "status": {
                        "response": "none",
                        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "type": "required",
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "Gregory Degruy",
                        "address": "grdegr@microsoft.com"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "organizer": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Greg Degruy",
                    "address": "Gregory.Degruy@microsoft.com"
                }
            },
            "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADc5NzQyYWI2LWMxOTctNDRmZi05ZTA3LWE3NmRmYmY1MDQ0MgBGAAAAAADXlwbV2STsRLeDUWHghS8MBwDHXzszvWCLTrbQs5TTKyesAAAAtujXAAAoP%2BtHHJf4RKg59YJl%2Bd8XAAAEs3bpAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewModel=ICalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory",
            "onlineMeetingUrl": null
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"KD/rRxyX+ESoOfWCZfnfFwAAPP4w8g==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADc5NzQyYWI2LWMxOTctNDRmZi05ZTA3LWE3NmRmYmY1MDQ0MgBGAAAAAADXlwbV2STsRLeDUWHghS8MBwDHXzszvWCLTrbQs5TTKyesAAAAtujXAAAoP_tHHJf4RKg59YJl_d8XAAAEs3cBAAA=",
            "createdDateTime": "2015-09-28T19:17:52.276469Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-10-05T19:27:50.3175476Z",
            "changeKey": "KD/rRxyX+ESoOfWCZfnfFwAAPP4w8g==",
            "categories": [],
            "originalStartTimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Custom",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Custom",
            "responseStatus": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000C00F90AFE7F9D001000000000000000010000000161F82080B826D4CBCB580B6CA119A08",
            "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
            "isReminderOn": false,
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "subject": "Azure Exam 532",
            "body": {
                "contentType": "text",
                "content": "\r\n"
            },
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "importance": "normal",
            "sensitivity": "normal",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2015-10-05T15:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2015-10-05T19:30:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "location": {
                "displayName": "Testing Center"
            },
            "isAllDay": false,
            "isCancelled": false,
            "isOrganizer": true,
            "recurrence": null,
            "responseRequested": true,
            "seriesMasterId": null,
            "showAs": "busy",
            "type": "singleInstance",
            "attendees": [],
            "organizer": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Greg Degruy",
                    "address": "Gregory.Degruy@microsoft.com"
                }
            },
            "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADc5NzQyYWI2LWMxOTctNDRmZi05ZTA3LWE3NmRmYmY1MDQ0MgBGAAAAAADXlwbV2STsRLeDUWHghS8MBwDHXzszvWCLTrbQs5TTKyesAAAAtujXAAAoP%2BtHHJf4RKg59YJl%2Bd8XAAAEs3cBAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewModel=ICalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory",
            "onlineMeetingUrl": null
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `SeriesMasterId` would only apply to single occurrences of a recurring event, which you won't see with `/me/events`. Getting events that way returns only the master event. Try [listing a calendar view](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview), which will expand recurring events.

Comment: In the REST example `/users/<id | userPrincipalName>/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}` what would be an example of a param to place in the `/<id | userPrincipalName>` field and can the `/users` field be replaced with the "me" param?

Comment: You can use their primary SMTP address there, and yes, you can use `/me` in place of the `/users/<id>/`.

Comment: perfect! I'll test out using `/me` in place of `/users/<id | userPrincipalName>`

Comment: I am still seeing a null SeriesMasterId when using the suggested api call. Here's the call I used `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2015-09-30T15:57:28-07:00&endDateTime=2016-10-20T10:13:32-07:00`

Comment: Post the JSON representation of one of these events.

Comment: I've added the JSON to my original post.

Comment: Those both have `type` of `singleInstance`, meaning they are not recurring, so there would be no series master in this case. You want to look at appointments that have a `type` of `occurrence`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126260/discussion-between-greg-degruy-and-jason-johnston).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need SeriesMasterId to download the instances of a series.
You can check recurrence object in respones and send those meeting ids (id) in below sample API

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{meeting_id}/instances?startDateTime=2019-04-08T09:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2019-04-30T09:00:00.0000000&$select=subject,bodyPreview,seriesMasterId,type,recurrence,start,end](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/%7Bmeeting_id%7D/instances?startDateTime=2019-04-08T09:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2019-04-30T09:00:00.0000000&$select=subject,bodyPreview,seriesMasterId,type,recurrence,start,end)

Comment: it is only giving 10 Occurences