# Microsoft Graph - Filter calendarView by seriesMasterId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I would like to be able to get **all** the instances of a recurring event (versus getting all but the "master" event using *events/id/instances*) and, to do that, I'm thinking of using *calendarView*.

However, to do so I need to filter the *calendarView* by the **seriesMasterId**, which so far I have not been able to do - I always get an empty object as response. The solution [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114452/microsoft-graph-api-calendar-api-null-seriesmasterid) works fine for the query

```
$filter=seriesMasterId+ne+null
```

but, with a query like

```
$filter=seriesMasterId+eq+'{id}'
```

I always get the empty object response.

Am I missing something here, or am I trying to achieve something that, for some reason, cannot be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I kinda of went ahead of myself with this question. For some reason, I was under the impression that the query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{event_id}/instances?(...)
```

Would return all the instances but the original master event, which **is not** the case. So, this query actually solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my test result, the seriesMasterId just have two choice(null or id),and the id which is not null will have the same value in the same query:
{ "@odata.etag": "","id": "", "subject": "Xaml Consulting Lunch",            "seriesMasterId": "AAMkADQ5OWMzMGEwLTg4ZjktNDk1Ny05NzFmLWRhZjg4ODU0YzUwYwBGAAAAAACtqDzk9UzLSpZsdesjndr1BwCjlNm_4oJfQqC8bkoOkcE6AAAAVvspAADOQt_-TwFOSKPNYFfSAG7oAACPgVuHAAA=",            "type": "occurrence"        },{            "@odata.etag"",            "id": "",            "subject": "Canceled: Cosmos DB Experiment - Weekly ",            "seriesMasterId": "AAMkADQ5OWMzMGEwLTg4ZjktNDk1Ny05NzFmLWRhZjg4ODU0YzUwYwBGAAAAAACtqDzk9UzLSpZsdesjndr1BwCjlNm_4oJfQqC8bkoOkcE6AAAAVvspAADOQt_-TwFOSKPNYFfSAG7oAAByPWvdAAA=",            "type": "occurrence"        }

The demo data from old officail docs also show the same result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/sync-calendar-view

So we can guess, the PG have no further handle for the seriesMasterId, you can try the following filter: $filter=type eq 'occurrence'

Comment: Filtering by 'ocurrence' will indeed result in recurring events, but all of them. If I have several recurring events, all of their instances would be returned, so this is really not the ideal solution for me, as I want to get **all** the instances of a recurring event.